# Android/Tensorflow: Why is RandomShuffleQueue needed for testing?

Tags: android, c, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to test a learnt model under Python on android, I'm on Tensorflow 0.9.
To do so, I freezed my graph to have a single pb file with the graph and weight. I used Queues to manage my learning batches.

When running my session on Android, I specify the input tensor by its name "input_node", which is the data layer as input in my network.

```
X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, W, H, 1], name="input_node")
```

and call the "output_node" layer :

```
output = tf.reshape(h_fc11, shape=[-1, 8], name="output_node")
```

Here is the call in tensorflow_jni.cc:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, tensorflow::Tensor> > input_tensors({{"input_node", input_tensor}});
s = session->Run(input_tensors, output_names, {}, &output_tensors);
```

The batch generation is done before, so it should not been used when testing.
But I have the following error:
tensorflow_jni.cc:312 Error during inference: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'RandomShuffleQueue' with these attrs
[[Node: shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue = RandomShuffleQueuecapacity=10750, component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], container="", min_after_dequeue=10000, seed=0, seed2=0, shapes=[[10000], [8]], shared_name=""]]

It seems that the batch generation layer is called (my images are 100x100 and I have 8 outputs), but I don't know why.

When testing the same model with the same input/output layers though the image_labelling.cc directly on Mac (building with Bazel), I don't have the error.

I do not understand why the RandomShuffleQueue is needed when testing. Am I missing something to specify the part of the graph I want to use? Are all the layers of the graph verified even if not used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still working on the documentation for this, but I think the optimize_for_inference script should help you here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference.py

You pass in a frozen graph, the input nodes, and output nodes, and it removes all of the other ops that aren't needed.

Comment: Thanks @Pete, useful function indeed. I'm using Tensorflow 0.9 and try to adapt it, but it seems to be many differences between master and 0.9 (graph_util, node_def_pb2, strip_unused_lib ...). Do you think this could work?